# This SHA and context has reached the maximum number of statuses in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

In single pipeline we are checking out from 4 repositories. Out of these 4 one is our primary repository where majority of our app code is present.

So we make lot of commits to this single repo but not so frequently to the other repos. We set gitHubCommitStatus for all the repos in a single build.

After running build we run into the GitHub limitation "This SHA and context has reached the maximum number of statuses." for the repos where don't make very frequent commits.

To resolve this right now, whenever we run into this problem, we push dummy commits so that the SHA for the last commit changes. We want to get over this manual intervention. How do we solve this problem?

We use Jenkinsfile. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-commit-status